# Reusing Deallocated Cursor again for deletion

Tags: sql-server-2008, cursor

I have declared a Cursor which fetches me all Ticket Ids created on a particular month and I am using it for insertion.

Once Insertion is Success, I am Deallocating the Cursor and Commiting the Transaction.

-->>Now I want to Delete the records based on the Success message. Like If messaage = 'Success', then Delete.

But problem is I have to pass that Ticket Ids to delete.

---

DECLARE @Tickets CURSOR
BEGIN TRANSACTION INSERTION;

```
    SET @Tickets= CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR SELECT TICKET_ID FROM TICKETMASTER
```

Then INSERT Query where I am passing Ticket Ids to insert in the table

open @Tickets 
CLOSE @Tickets 
DEALLOCATE @Tickets
SET @message='SUCCESS'

### COMMIT TRANSACTION INSERTION;

Now I am Beginning another Transaction for Deletion

BEGIN TRANSACTION DELETION;

Here I want to delete again the rows which I have inserted only when @message is success and I have to pass the Ticket ids to delete.

like Delete from TICKETMASTER Where TICKET_ID = @tickets

--

I don't want to set the cursor again to get the ticket ids. Want to use the same @tickets Cursor for deletion just by opening again.

I have deallocated the @tickets cursor, so Can I reuse it again just by giving

Open @tickets
if(message='Success')
delete from TICKETMASTER Where TicketId = @tickets

Answer (score 0):

You could select ticketid into #temptable from Ticketmaster, and use that as the source for both cursors. Or you can do both the inserts and deletes within the same cursor body.